# how can i overcome this fatal error when i was run this SOAP API?

Tags: php, api, soap, fatal-error

i was used the sms API in my Bluehost hosting. when i was run the code it shown like

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV3/EnterpriseSMSWS?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV3/EnterpriseSMSWS?wsdl" in /storage/ssd4/825/11729825/public_html/sms/sms_backend.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd4/825/11729825/public_html/sms/sms_backend.php(58): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://smeapps....') #1 /storage/ssd4/825/11729825/public_html/sms/sms_backend.php(101): getClient() #2 /storage/ssd4/825/11729825/public_html/sms/sms_backend.php(27): createSession('', 'esyyyyy', 'xxxx', '') #3 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/825/11729825/public_html/sms/sms_backend.php on line 58`

here this is my code

```
<?php



$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
//$alias = $_REQUEST['alias'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$number = $_REQUEST['numbers'];





$session=createSession('',$username,$password,'');
sendMessages($session,'XXXX',$message,$number,0); // 1 for promotional messages, 0 for normal message 
closeSession($session);


$session=createSession('',$username,$password,'');
getMessagesFromShortCode($session,"shortcode");
getMessagesFromLongNumber($session,"longnum");
closeSession($session);





//create soap client
function getClient()
{





ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $client = new SoapClient("http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV3/EnterpriseSMSWS?wsdl");

    return $client;
    
    

}


//serviceTest
function serviceTest($id,$username,$password,$customer)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $user = new stdClass();
    $user->id = '';
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->customer = '';

    $serviceTest = new stdClass();
    $serviceTest->arg0 = $user;

    return $client->serviceTest($serviceTest);

}

//create session
function createSession($id,$username,$password,$customer)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $user = new stdClass();
    $user->id = $id;
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->customer = $customer;

    $createSession = new stdClass();
    $createSession->user = $user;

    $createSessionResponse = new stdClass();
    $createSessionResponse = $client->createSession($createSession);

    return $createSessionResponse->return;

}

//check if session is valid
function isSession($session)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $isSession = new stdClass();
    $isSession->session = $session;

    $isSessionResponse = new stdClass();
    $isSessionResponse = $client->isSession($isSession);

    return $isSessionResponse->return;
}

//send SMS to recipients
function sendMessages($session,$alias,$message,$recipients,$messageType)
{
    $client=getClient();

    $smsMessage= new stdClass();
    $smsMessage->message=$message;
    $smsMessage->messageId="";
    $smsMessage->recipients=$recipients;
    $smsMessage->retries="";
    $smsMessage->sender=$alias;
    $smsMessage->messageType=$messageType;
    $smsMessage->sequenceNum="";
    $smsMessage->status="";
    $smsMessage->time="";
    $smsMessage->type="";
    $smsMessage->user="";

    $sendMessages = new stdClass();
    $sendMessages->session = $session;
    $sendMessages->smsMessage = $smsMessage;

    $sendMessagesResponse = new stdClass();
    $sendMessagesResponse = $client->sendMessages($sendMessages);

    return $sendMessagesResponse->return;
}

//send Unicoded SMS to recipients
function sendMessagesMultiLang($session,$alias,$message,$recipients,$messageType)
{
    $client=getClient();

    $smsMessageMultiLang = new stdClass();
    $smsMessageMultiLang->message=$message;
    $smsMessageMultiLang->messageId="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->recipients=$recipients;
    $smsMessageMultiLang->retries="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->sender=$alias;

    $smsMessageMultiLang->messageType=$messageType;
    $smsMessageMultiLang->sequenceNum="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->status="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->time="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->type="";
    $smsMessageMultiLang->user="";

    $sendMessagesMultiLang = new stdClass();
    $sendMessagesMultiLang->session = $session;
    $sendMessagesMultiLang->smsMessageMultiLang = $smsMessageMultiLang;

    $sendMessagesMultiLangResponse = new stdClass();
    $sendMessagesMultiLangResponse = $client->sendMessagesMultiLang($sendMessagesMultiLang);

    return $sendMessagesMultiLangResponse->return;
}

//send Campaign SMS to recipients
function sendCampaignMessages($session,$alias,$message,$recipients,$datetime,$multilanguage,$messageType)
{
    $client=getClient();

    $smsCampaignMessage = new stdClass();
    $smsCampaignMessage->message = $message;
    $smsCampaignMessage->messageId = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->recipients = $recipients;
    $smsCampaignMessage->retries = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->sender = $alias;
    $smsCampaignMessage->messageType=$messageType;
    $smsCampaignMessage->sequenceNum = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->status = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->time = $datetime;
    $smsCampaignMessage->type = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->user = "";
    $smsCampaignMessage->esmClass = $multilanguage;
    
    $sendCampaignMessages=new stdClass();
    $sendCampaignMessages->session=$session;
    $sendCampaignMessages->smsCampaignMessage=$smsCampaignMessage;
    

    $sendCampaignMessagesResponse = new stdClass();
    $sendCampaignMessagesResponse = $client->sendCampaignMessages($sendCampaignMessages);

    return $sendCampaignMessagesResponse->return;
}

//renew session 
function renewSession($session)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $renewSession = new stdClass();
    $renewSession->session = $session;

    $renewSessionResponse = new stdClass();
    $renewSessionResponse = $client->renewSession($renewSession);

    return $renewSessionResponse->return;

}


//close session
function closeSession($session)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $closeSession = new stdClass();
    $closeSession->session = $session;

    $client->closeSession($closeSession);

}

//retrieve messages from shortcode
function getMessagesFromShortCode($session,$shortCode)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $getMessagesFromShortCode = new stdClass();
    $getMessagesFromShortCode->session = $session;
    $getMessagesFromShortCode->shortcode = $shortCode;

    $getMessagesFromShortcodeResponse = new stdClass();
    $getMessagesFromShortcodeResponse->return = "";
    $getMessagesFromShortcodeResponse = $client->getMessagesFromShortcode($getMessagesFromShortCode);
    
    if(property_exists($getMessagesFromShortcodeResponse,'return'))
    return $getMessagesFromShortcodeResponse->return;
    
    else return NULL;

}

//retrieve delivery report
function getDeliveryReports($session,$alias)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $getDeliveryReports = new stdClass();
    $getDeliveryReports->session = $session;
    $getDeliveryReports->alias = $alias;

    $getDeliveryReportsResponse = new stdClass();
    $getDeliveryReportsResponse->return = "";
    $getDeliveryReportsResponse = $client->getDeliveryReports($getDeliveryReports);
    
    if(property_exists($getDeliveryReportsResponse,'return'))
    return $getDeliveryReportsResponse->return;
    
    else return NULL;

}

//retrieve messages from longnumber
function getMessagesFromLongNumber($session,$longNumber)
{

    $client = getClient();

    $getMessagesFromLongNumber = new stdClass();
    $getMessagesFromLongNumber->session = $session;
    $getMessagesFromLongNumber->longNumber=$longNumber;

    $getMessagesFromLongNumberResponse = new stdClass();
    $getmessagesFromLongNumberResponse->return = "";
    $getMessagesFromLongNumberResponse = $client->getMessagesFromLongNumber($getMessagesFromLongNumber);
    
    if(property_exists($getMessagesFromLongNumberResponse,'return'))
    return $getMessagesFromLongNumberResponse->return;
    
    else return NULL;
    
}
 
 ?>
```

this code works in Localhost very well... but in my hosting (Bluehost) it was shown fatal error like that.

can any one help me to resolve this error??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you need to have the extension `php_openssl` enabled on your server for it to work.

You can do this yourself on most hosting services by going to your PHP settings -> look for the option `php_openssl.dll` or `php_openssl` and enable it.

If you have access to your `php.ini` file, you could look for the line that says `extension=php_openssl.dll` and if this has a `;` at the start like this `;extension=php_openssl.dll`, remove the `;` from the start so it reads `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

This should solve it for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i was removed the ; from php.ini. but it still didn't work....is there any another problem or it will take the time?

Comment: Please share with me how you did it and from where. Bluehosting or your localhost?

Comment: allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
extension=php_openssl.dll
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 260M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
upload_max_filesize = 256M
zlib.output_compression = Off

Comment: It will not work by just adding a php.ini file to your bluehosting. Here is a link to follow and do this well according to your host: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/configure-the-php-environment-with-php-ini